# conversion from unsigned char* to const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, cross-platform, type-conversion

I am using the following code to convert a string from `unsigned char*` to `const wchar_t*` . The error I am getting is that only a few words are being converted properly while the rest is garbled value.

**CODE**

```
unsigned char* temp = fileUtils->getFileData("levels.json", "r", &size);
const char* temp1 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp);
size_t len = mbstowcs(nullptr, &temp1[0], 0);
if (len == -1) {

} else {
    wchar_t* levelData = new wchar_t();
    mbstowcs(&levelData[0], &temp1[0], size*10);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
temp1 = "[{"scaleFactor": 1}][{"scaleFactor": 2}][{"scaleFactor": 3}][{"scaleFactor": 4}][{"scaleFactor": 5}][{"scaleFactor": 6}][{"scaleFactor": 7}][{"scaleFactor": 8}][{"scaleFactor": 9}][{"scaleFactor": 10}]"

levelData = "[{"scaleFactor": 1}][{"scaleFactor": 2}][{"scaleFactor": 3}][{"scaleFactor": 4}][{"scaleFactor": 5}][{"scaleFactor": 6}][{"scaleFactor": 7}][{"s慣敬慆瑣牯㨢㠠嵽筛猢慣敬慆瑣牯㨢㤠嵽筛猢慣敬慆瑣牯㨢ㄠ細ﵝ﷽꯽ꮫꮫꮫﺫﻮ"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hard code the buffer size if you're going to allocate it dynamically (with new).

```
wchar_t* levelData = new wchar_t[len+1];
mbstowcs(&levelData[0], &temp1[0], len);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am still getting garbage values at the end. How do I get rid of that? Is it because of incorrect length?

Comment: `sizeof (levelData)` gives you the size of a pointer, which is definitely not right.  -1

Comment: Please learn more before answering the questions. `len` in this case will be always 0 or -1.

Comment: @Number47 No, when using `nullptr` as the first parameter (dest pointer) you get the length of the converted string regardless of the last parameter (max characters to convert). So `len` does give the correct length.

Comment: @Simon, Oh, I did not know there is such behavior. Still, it is non-standard -- _POSIX specifies a common extension: if dst is a null pointer, this function returns the number of wide characters that would be written to dst, if converted._ -- Besides, both your and my solutions are probably wrong, while `temp` array probably is not followed by `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
wchar_t* levelData = new wchar_t();
mbstowcs(&levelData[0], &temp1[0], size*10);
```

That allocated enough memory for exactly ONE character.  That's not enough to store your string, so of course things will not work right.

Also, where'd that `10` come from?

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that I am C++ novice. With `size*10` I was trying to set a large size so it holds all characters.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, it is a place for asking and learning, I believe, not a playground for our sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BenVoigt, found the mistake. Changed the code to this-

```
wchar_t levelData[200];
mbstowcs(&levelData[0], &temp1[0], size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char* temp = fileUtils->getFileData("levels.json", "r", &size);
const char* temp1 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp);

wchar_t* levelData = new wchar_t[size];
int last_char_size = 0;

mbtowc(NULL, 0, 0);
for (wchar_t* position = levelData; size > 0; position++)
{
    last_char_size = mbtowc(position, temp1, size);
    if (last_char_size <= 0) break;
    else {
        temp1 += last_char_size;
        size -= last_char_size;
    }
}

if (last_char_size == -1)
{
    std::cout  << "Invalid encoding" << std::endl;
}

delete[] temp; // * probably
```

The marked line (*) depends on, whether the `fileUtils->getFileData` allocates a memory block for `temp` and the object of `fileUtils` does not manage it by its own. -- Which is most probable. However you should check the documentation.

The `size` should be perfectly enough size for the `levelData` array, while whithin `[]` you specify the number of elements of the array, not the number of bytes(aka `char`s). - In this case, it is the number of wide characters. Which can not be more, then read `char`s.

Another thing you should be aware, the `fileUtils->getFileData` probably reads binary date. So the text in `temp` is not followed by 0. So, later string functions - like `wcstok` - called on it, will shoot your foot off.

And one another. If you are not familiar with the construction

```
    function_on_arrays( target,  source,  size )
```

Remember your program in C/C++ don't know the sizes of `target` and `source`. But probably, you do not want to the function do something beyond them. So this is what for the `size` mainly is. - Your manual way to say, on how many elements you want to perform the action to not go beyond the arrays's data.

**Edit:**
The earlier solution was wrong, as mistakenly treating the last parameter of `mbstowcs` as the number of characters in the source.