# Adding "L" to a string literal works to make it wide string, but not to a variable

Tags: c++, string, widechar, widestring

The macro `#define STR16(x) L ## x` works when applied to string literals:

```
STR16("Hello")     // fine, this is translated to L"Hello"
```

but not to variables:

```
STR16(x)     // fails, this is translated to Lx, and the variable Lx doesn't exist
```

In [line 200 of this useful library](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/0c4ed2b854f71bdbb324feded5176ab2a57d3be6/WDL/IPlug/IPlugVST3.cpp#L200), there is a bug:

```
Parameter* param = new RangeParameter( STR16(p->GetNameForHost()), ...
```

will be translated to

```
Parameter* param = new RangeParameter( Lp->GetNameForHost(), ...
```

which fails, because `Lp` is an undeclared identifier.

**How to do the same than adding `L` to a string literal, to a string variable `const char *` ?**

Comment: How to convert narrow to wide, depends on the narrow encoding. But since wide in practice is some Unicode encoding, and since Unicode is a superset of Latin-1 which is a superset of ASCII, if the narrow encoding is either ASCII or Latin-1 then you can just widen each code point.

Comment: Note that the name `STR16` is platform-dependent: it's true in Windows, but mostly not elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409350/convert-const-char-to-const-wchar-t)

Comment: Have you filed an issue on GitHub for this? If not, you probably should.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just did: [STR16 issue in IPlugVST3.cpp](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/issues/61).

Comment: If you get an answer here first, you can submit a patch to the library. If the library gets fixed first, let us know how by answering your own question. Either way, good work.